# Iphone App - how to reproduce inapp browser actions ?

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, django, webview

I have a problem with an IOS app that is being developed.

We agreed (with an outside development company) to develop a hybrid application : both webview and native code. My website : http://youmind.it is perfectly responsive and the functionnalities of my website work fine (imagine a feed of photos that you can like, comment and share). You can like, comment, report, share a photo from any browser on a mobile phone.

On the first tests on the app however, the functionalities on the webviews really dont work. Either something happens visually but is not registered in database, or nothing happens. The dev company tells me this is because of my website which doesnt work on the browser inapp. Problem is : they dont give me ways to test my website on such a browser, therefore no way to tests changes.

We checked that javascript was correctly enabled on the Iphone APP, and now I am totally powerless... Do you know If I can reproduce (say on a computer, or even on an Iphone), the behavior of my responsive website, in order to make tests and validate that there is a problem on the website side (and not on the appside) ?

Thanks for your help !

Martin

Note : website works with python / django. Not sure it can help.

Comment: I don't understand...do they say: this is not working, but we wont tell you how to reproduce errors?

Comment: Also, i have not worked on IOS, but they have an emulator that runs fast enough to test your apps.

Comment: We need to see some sort of code in order to help you. Saying that your "webview is just responding but not registering" is basically the same as saying "it doesn't work". And by not "registering", is the webview supposed to give some sort of feedback? If so, then the webview isn't delegating properly. That's just my best guess though.

Comment: @cdcc7788. Yes there is a fact "it is not working". When you like an image on the app, it adds a +1 but not on the website, or nothing happens. When you reload the feed, + 1 has disappeared. Answer is : it is on your side, which I dont mind, but I would like to see how iI can reproduce the problem to work on it (mobile website works fine) !

Comment: @ReverseEffect, yes I'll try to work this "not delegating properly" ;) thx. I'll see what i can do with getting some code which concerns the webview. thx again

Comment: I should probably rephrase what I meant, you don't have to show all your code, just get whoever's developing on it to make a new code snippet to represent something about it and then it would make it easier to diagnose it. Otherwise, we're just working on best guesses. Good luck with your project!